# Redux pagination not working when items are removed from list

Tags: javascript, redux, pagination

Consider this simple Redux app:

```
const items = (state = [], action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD_ITEMS":
         return addItems(state, action.items)
      case "REMOVE_ITEMS":
         return removeItems(state, action.items)
      default:
         return state
   }
}

const page = (state = 1, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case "PREVIOUS":
         return state - 1
      case "NEXT":
         return state + 1
      default:
         return state
   }
}

const reducer = combineReducers({ items, page })
```

As you can see, the state has two parts:

- `items`: A list of items. Items can be added and removed from the list.
- `page`: The current page of a pagination system in the UI. Let's say that ten items at a time should be displayed, and the user can navigate between pages.

The UI is rendered with Redux:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   const start = (state.page - 1) * 10
   const stop = state.page * 10 - 1
   return {
      visibleItems: state.items.splice(start, stop)
   }
}
```

Currently this app has a bug. If the user is on page five and all but eleven items are removed, `page` will suddenly have an invalid value. There is no page five anymore, only page one and two! The desired behaviour is that it should change to two, the highest valid page.

I could handle this situation by adding a `case "REMOVE_ITEMS"` to the `page` reducer. But `page` doesn't know what the new value of `items.length` will be. For it to know that, it would need access to the `items` state and then recalculate the result of `removeItems`. This doesn't sound like good design to me.

Another option would be to just write one reducer, but it would be quite a messy one and I hesitate to merge these pieces of code with separate tasks.

What is the best way to handla a situation like this?

Comment: How do you handle pagination rendering?

Comment: @AntonAbramov See my edit.

Comment: as i can see you prepair visible item for table props, but share the part of component where you render pages list. You have the problem with updating this list, right?

Comment: @AntonAbramov The list updates fine. The problem is that when you remove item, you might be on a page that no longer exists. The `visibleItems` prop then comes out as an empty array.

Comment: i think you could add if statement like this "if current page from store greater than max page, switch page to max page". Also you could create additional action and section for page reducer which will return given page number

Comment: @AntonAbramov Good suggestion! Adding that if statement to `mapStateToProps` would be a big improvement. But it would still give me the problem that if someone later adds new items, the page will magically be bumped up again for no reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181242/discussion-between-anton-abramov-and-anders).